# Table with power law indexing

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, logarithmic-scale, integral-transforms

I am using the Drubin numerical inversion out of Laplace space, and need to see how the function performs over a wide range of values, covering multiple logrithmic cycles.  However, the inversion is slow, and when I need the definition at small times, it takes a very long time to run through the whole range. I tried the Crump accelerator, but it is very memory intensive, so I'd rather not use it.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
adurb[tmax_, alpha_, tol_] := adurb[tmax, alpha, tol] = alpha - Log[tol]/(8 tmax) // N
cdurb[F_, s_, tmax_, alpha_, tol_, k_] := F /. s -> adurb[tmax, alpha, tol] + I Pi k/(4 tmax) // N
cdurb[F_, s_, tmax_, alpha_, tol_, 0] := F/2 /. s -> adurb[tmax, alpha, tol] // N

NLInvDurb[F_, s_, t_, j_, tmax_, alpha_, tol_] := NLInvDurb[F, s, t, j, tmax, alpha, tol] = Exp[adurb[tmax, alpha, tol] t]/(4 tmax)*Sum[Re[cdurb[F, s, tmax, alpha, tol, k]] Cos[k Pi t/(4 tmax)] - Im[cdurb[F, s, tmax, alpha, tol, k]] Sin[k Pi t/(4 tmax)], {k, 0, j}] // N    

ini = 0.001;
imax = 1000;
istep = 0.01;
NStep = 1000;

datrul1 = {CD -> 0.1, CfD -> 16, ϕ -> 10, α -> 0.3, η -> 10, S -> 0.1};

qD1[u_] = 1/u^2 (1 + 
 u^2 CD (Pi/CfD 1/(u (u/η + (2 Sqrt[u])/CfD)^(1/2))) + 
 u S CD)/((1 + ϕ CD u^2 - (ϕ CD u^2)/(
   u + 1/α)) (Pi/CfD 1/(
    u (u/η + (2 Sqrt[u])/CfD)^(1/2)) + S/u)) /. datrul1;

qPlot1 = ListLogLogPlot[Table[
{t, NLInvDurb[qD1[u], u, t, NStep, imax, 0, 0.00000001]},
{t, ini, imax, istep}], PlotStyle -> Red, PlotLegends -> {α} /. datrul1, Joined -> True] // N
```

Running the code as is, will take a very long time.  What I would like to do is have a varying time step on a logrithmic scale. So say 10 points for each log cycle.  i.e. 0.001,0.002,...,0.009,0.01,0.02,...,0.09,0.1,...

Any ideas on how to handle this are much appreciated.

Just as a side, I have been using a simpler function to test the program, so you don't have to spend so much time with the long equation:

```
F[u_] = 1/(u^2 + 1);
f[t_] = Sin[t];

DurbTab = ListPlot[Table[
{t, NLInvDurb[F[u], u, t, 1000, 3 Pi, 0, 0.00000001]},
{t, 0, 3 Pi, 1/10}], PlotStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotLegends -> {"Approximation"} // N];
RealTab = Plot[{f[r]}, {r, 0, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotLegends -> {"Real Solution"}];
Show[{DurbTab, RealTab}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Perhaps, use integer index `i`, and define `t` in the first argument of `Table` as `10^(i/10-3)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a power law list of indices with

```
ini = 0.001;
imax = 1000;
indices = 
  Append[Flatten @ Transpose @ Table[k PowerRange[ini, imax - 1], {k, 9}], 
  imax]
```

> ```
> {0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.004, 0.005, 0.006, 0.007, 0.008, 0.009, 
>  0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 
>  0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 
>  1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 
>  10., 20., 30., 40., 50., 60., 70., 80., 90., 
>  100., 200., 300., 400., 500., 600., 700., 800., 900., 
>  1000}
> ```

and then index your table with

```
{t, indices}
```